# Is it possible to hide a json array from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, json

in order to use a javascript function, I have to use a json array, but I would like to be able to obscure the information in the DOM.

Below is an example:

```
<script>
    var arrayC = [{"id":null,"name":"Name","title":"Title"}];
    ..... function
</script>
```

I wish arrayC were obscured, is it possible? I searched online but I can't find anything, can you help me? thank you

Comment: The DOM doesn't contain any JSON arrays, such thing doesn't even exist in JS. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: use [Javascript Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) mybe it usefull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As soon as the script executes, `.remove()` the containing `<script>` tag:

```html
<script>
var arrayC = [{"id":null,"name":"Name","title":"Title"}];
console.log('doing something...');
document.currentScript.remove();
</script>
Right click and Inspect me!
```

Do note that this doesn't prevent users from seeing the code - they can still see it in the page source. This only removes it from the DOM.

If you also want to keep `arrayC` from populating the global object, put the entire script into an IIFE, or use `const` or `let` instead of `var`:

```
(() => {
  var arrayC = [{"id":null,"name":"Name","title":"Title"}];
  console.log('doing something...');
  document.currentScript.remove();
})();
```

Data that should be kept secret from the client should never be sent to their computer in the first place. No matter how you try to disguise something, if you send it to the client, they may be able to figure it out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use external Script file instead script inside html page directly. to do this simply create a javascript file(.js extension) and include that file into this html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<filename>.js"></script>
```

upto some extended directly you array will not be displayed. if not want to show for high security convert it to json string and encryption and decryption at server side. and assign that encrpted variable to js variable, so it will always show encrypted string on sourcefile in javascript.